# Image carousel in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, components, vuejs3, carousel, vue-composition-api

I'm building a cinema website, and are currently on the part where I want to place the movies in a carousel like effect so that you can swipe through the row. As you can see on like Netflix or Diseny Plus. I have this code in my Vue component.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  import Vue from "vue"
  import { createApp, ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
  import axios from 'axios';
  import VueTouch from 'vue2-touch-events';
  

    interface IMovie {
      _id: string;
      title: string;
      poster: string;
    }

    const movies = ref<IMovie[]>([]);

    onMounted(async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/movie");
            movies.value = response.data;
            console.log(movies.value)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Failed to retrieve posters:", error);
        }
    })

</script>

<template>
    <div class="large-container">
      <h1>Kommande filmer</h1>
      <div class="medium-container">
        <div v-for="movie in movies" :key="movie._id" class="movies">
          <img 
            :src="`http://localhost:3000/movie/image/${movie.poster}`"
            :alt="movie.title"
          />
          <h3>{{ movie.title }}</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
  .large-container {
    padding-top: 40px;
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin: auto;
  }

  h1 {
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: #eeeeee;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }

  .medium-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
.movies {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  img {
    max-height: 300px;
    padding: 0 20px;
  }

  h3 {
    margin: 5px 0 0 20px;
    color: #eeeeee;
  }
</style>
```

I've been trying a bunch of different things to create an image carousel as the ones you can see on most of the cinema websites, but I don't manage to get it to work. Can someone help me?

Swiper, vue2-touch-events and probably something more.

Answer (score 0):

you can use vue-splide component or swiper for your project.

with this example you can create a carousel for your website

```
npm i @splidejs/vue-splide
```

```
<template>
  <Splide :options="slideOptions" aria-label="tour carousel label">

    <SplideSlide v-for="movie in movies" :key="movie._id">
      <img :src="`http://localhost:3000/movie/image/${movie.poster}`"
            :alt="movie.title" />
    </SplideSlide>

  </Splide>
</template>

<script setup>
import { Splide, SplideSlide } from '@splidejs/vue-splide';
import '@splidejs/vue-splide/css';

//splide options
const slideOptions = {
   type : 'loop',
  perPage : 3,
  perMove : 1,
}
</script>
```

and you can find any options that you want in this link :
https://splidejs.com/guides/options/

Comment: Seems like  splidejs/vue-splide doesn't work with TS?

Comment: it supports typescripts and hasn't any problem. i always use vue-splide in my projects and it's fine @MelvinKempe

Comment: Hmm, I don't manage to make it work

Comment: This is the error message I get from the first import: Could not find a declaration file for module '@splidejs/vue-splide'. 'c:/Users/melvi/Documents/GitHub/Ange-FH-Vue/Client/node_modules/@splidejs/vue-splide/dist/js/vue-splide.esm.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  There are types at 'c:/Users/melvi/Documents/GitHub/Ange-FH-Vue/Client/node_modules/@splidejs/vue-splide/src/js/index.ts', but this result could not be resolved when respecting package.json "exports". The '@splidejs/vue-splide' library may need to update its package.json or typings.ts(7016)